# How to register a .eu domain?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains, tld-restrictions

I want register a domain under the .eu TLD, but I don't live in Europe [which is a requiriment to that].

I'd like to know if there is any website which register the domain on its name or any other solution.

Comment: www.1and1.co.uk will register .eu domains for you, however I don't know if it checks your address.

Comment: @Ian: I need to a UK address to use it.. =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are aware already that this is not intended according to the regulations outlined in *Article 4* of the respective [EC regulation 733/2002](http://www.eurid.eu/files/733_2002_EN_1.pdf):

> 1. The Registry shall:
>      [...]
>      (b) register domain names in the .eu TLD through any accredited
>      .eu Registrar requested by any:
>      (i) undertaking having its registered office, central administration
>      or principal place of business within the Community, or
>      (ii) organisation established within the Community
>      without prejudice to the application of national law, or
>      (iii) natural person resident within the Community

I'm not aware of any official/legal way to achieve what you desire, neither of any 'grey hat' option to circumvent this restriction (though the latter <strike>will likely be possible somehow as usual</strike> seems indeed possible as per [Joel Ethertons answer](#3349) - make sure to read my comment as well though ...).

So I'm afraid that depending on you concrete needs your will need to either establish an official undertaking within the Community or at least contract with an affiliate who is resident in the EU (i.e. someone who is not just performing the registration *on behalf of you*, rather is a real business partner and willing to take legal responsibility regarding the domain ownership as such!).

Comment: There are companies that specialise in your #2 option. We used them when we needed to register a `.co.hk` domain. They will receive your mail, scan it and email it to your in a PDF so that you can have a local point of contact for international business dealings, without you ever having to leave the country or go through the rigmarole of setting up an international company.

Comment: @Farseeker - yeah, that's probably along the lines of what Júlio is looking for, but as I read things a registration *on behalf of Júlio* without any legal business relationship like you suggest would actually be considered fraudulent for `.eu` domains specifically - IANAL, but if `.eu` registrations are indeed offered somewhere with this simplistic approach it might indeed be qualified as 'grey hat' territory at least ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed anwer, I really would like to get that domain, but since it is just a personal project [would have a "cool domain"], I think it's not worth the problems I could have in the future.

Comment: @Júlio - indeed, the weird multiple company plus multiple domain indirections involved with the one option surfaced so far are pretty telling, as far as I'm concerned ...

Answer (score 5):

Go grey hat with [Network Solutions](http://www.networksolutions.com/). They provide proxy EU registrations through their affiliate corporation: http://www.networksolutions.com/support/registering-eu-domain-names-2/

Comment: +1 for digging up such an option at least (I've updated my answer accordingly) - I hadn't expected an offering like this from them (but am not surprised either of course). Hopefully the PHP errors currently surfaced on http://www.networksolutionsretail.com/eu/ are not a quality indicator for how they treat the legal issues involved ;) Hosting the customer license agreement on a separate domain (http://www.snnslicenseagreement.com/) is somewhat, let's say unusual/special as well ... If read from a distance its black text on white background definitely appears a bit grey to me indeed ;)

Comment: @Steffen Opel - Network Solutions has always been a bit loose when it comes to quality or legality. I recall back in 2000/2001 when they were in some bitter disputes of domain pirating because they were accepting just about any fax on an official looking letter head as a viable, legal domain transfer.

Comment: The Website really scaries me. I'll take a look, but the price is a bit high. I'd +1 if I had enough rep.

Comment: @Júlio Souza, +1, now you have the rep to upvote :) Remember to upvote the *checkmarked* answer also.

Answer (score 0):

If you live outside Europe my company can do this for you for 18€ / year :)
But with a minimum of 3 years.

Anyway if you look on Google there are dozens of registrars that can do this.

Comment: Do you offer this service for .uk domains also?